# Work with files in cordova and Ionic - compatibility iOS, Android

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic-view, cordova-plugin-file

For this question I have created [compatibility test project on GitHub](https://github.com/domino2/cordova_file_compatibility_project).

Initial state is set only to Ionic View application.

**Ionic Browser**

`ionic serve` show output as on picture *ionicBrowser.png*.

But If I uncomment in `www\js\index.js` line 32 and 33, then

- fileSystemRequest (webkitRequestFileSystem) is fine,
- fileEntry is fine,
- writing and reading file works as well.

**Ionic App**

For command `ionic upload`, the output on Android Device is as on picture *ionicView-android.png*.

iOS show me view output as on picture *ionicView-ios.png*.

**Native Application build by Ionic**

Command `ionic package build android` got me output on Android only with **device ready** event. Reason is I didn't add **cordova-plugin-file** to `package.json`

```
...,
"ionic-plugin-keyboard",
"cordova-plugin-file"],
"cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

After correction, I have got output *nativeAndroid.png*

In general, I can work with files only on Android devices (Ionic View or as an Native App).

I can't work with files on iOS in any possible way and this is my problem. I need work with files on iOS devices. I have thought that Cordova and Ionic make common environment, but this doesn't happens.

**Do I something wrong?**

## Update 1

I have tried build up application as a native package for Android under Windows by command `ionic run android`.

For this testing I have used Android device with Android 4.2.9 and Android emulator as well.

Don't forgot for `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file`.

Don't forgot for `ionic platform add android`.

I have got same view as on *nativeAndroid.png*.

## Update 2

I have used for this task Mac mini OS X El Capitan (10.11.5).

I have got problem with editing text files, so I have prepared everything on Windows and moved project to Mac.

I have worked with ionic view (`ionic upload`) and `ionic package build android` and 
I have got same views (*nativeAndroid.png*, *ionicView-android.png*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried build up application as a native for iOS in OS X ... by command `ionic run ios`.

For this testing I have used iOS emulator.

Don't forgot for `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file`.

Don't forgot for `ionic platform add ios`.

I have got same view as on *nativeAndroid.png*.

Everything works, universe is saved.

## Result

I need still test ionic view on iOS device (run ionic upload on OS X ...).

Probably development with ionic and cordova is platform oriented. If I want deploy iOS app, need Apple machine (Android on OS X is fine - see above - I mean `ionic package build android`).